# use webrtc get client IP report:ICE failed, add a STUN server and see about:webrtc for more details

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I used the following code snippet to get results on both the web side and the sandbox side.However, in my React code debugging, I always failed...

```
//get the IP addresses associated with an account
function getIPs(callback){
    var ip_dups = {};

    //compatibility for firefox and chrome
    var RTCPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection
        || window.mozRTCPeerConnection
        || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
    var useWebKit = !!window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;

    //bypass naive webrtc blocking using an iframe
    if(!RTCPeerConnection){
        //NOTE: you need to have an iframe in the page right above the script tag
        //
        //<iframe id="iframe" sandbox="allow-same-origin" style="display: none"></iframe>
        //<script>...getIPs called in here...
        //
        var win = iframe.contentWindow;
        RTCPeerConnection = win.RTCPeerConnection
            || win.mozRTCPeerConnection
            || win.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
        useWebKit = !!win.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
    }

    //minimal requirements for data connection
    var mediaConstraints = {
        optional: [{RtpDataChannels: true}]
    };

    var servers = {iceServers: [{urls: "stun:stun.services.mozilla.com"}]};

    //construct a new RTCPeerConnection
    var pc = new RTCPeerConnection(servers, mediaConstraints);

    function handleCandidate(candidate){
        //match just the IP address
        var ip_regex = /([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}|[a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})/
        var ip_addr = ip_regex.exec(candidate)[1];

        //remove duplicates
        if(ip_dups[ip_addr] === undefined)
            callback(ip_addr);

        ip_dups[ip_addr] = true;
    }

    //listen for candidate events
    pc.onicecandidate = function(ice){

        //skip non-candidate events
        if(ice.candidate)
            handleCandidate(ice.candidate.candidate);
    };

    //create a bogus data channel
    pc.createDataChannel("");

    //create an offer sdp
    pc.createOffer(function(result){

        //trigger the stun server request
        pc.setLocalDescription(result, function(){}, function(){});

    }, function(){});

    //wait for a while to let everything done
    setTimeout(function(){
        //read candidate info from local description
        var lines = pc.localDescription.sdp.split('\n');

        lines.forEach(function(line){
            if(line.indexOf('a=candidate:') === 0)
                handleCandidate(line);
        });
    }, 1000);
}

//Test: Print the IP addresses into the console
getIPs(function(ip){console.log(ip);});
```

> ```
> ICE failed, add a STUN server and see about:webrtc for more
> details:
> canTrickleIceCandidates: null
> currentLocalDescription: null
> currentRemoteDescription: null
> iceConnectionState: "failed"
> iceGatheringState: "gathering"
> idpLoginUrl: null
> localDescription: RTCSessionDescription`
> onaddstream: null
> onaddtrack: null
> ondatachannel: null
> onicecandidate:Login/</pc.onicecandidate()
> oniceconnectionstatechange: null
> onicegatheringstatechange: null
> onnegotiationneeded: null
> onsignalingstatechange: null
> ontrack: null
> peerIdentity: Promise { "pending" }
> ```